# How to serialize a Map<String, String> using Simple XML?

Tags: java, simple-framework

How would you go about serialising a Map using [simple XML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php) so that it looks something like:

```
<elem foo="value">key</elem>
```

Instead of the normal

```
<elem foo="key">value</elem>
```

(The map is one to many, and since this will be edited by humans, I wanted it to be clearer.)

**[EDIT]:** Doesn't Fix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
@ElementMap(entry="property", value="value", attribute=true, inline=true)
private Map<String, String> map;
```

or some combination, i.e. to use the other attributes of the [@ElementMap annotation](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/ElementMap.html) too?

Comment: Yes, I did just that in fact, but setting `attribute=true` sets the key as the attribute, and not the value.

Comment: so using value="value" instead of key="key" will not put them in reverse order? If so than that's a bug I think. To make it still work, you need to define your own template (see the docs) or as an alternative to make your own @ElementMap annotation (e.g. you can call it @ElementMapReversed that reversed that (until the team fixes that bug).

Comment: I don't think that the `key` and `value` parameters are used like this. These parameters define what the xml element is called when `inline=false`. For example: `@ElementMap(entry="spam",value="foo", key="bar")` would yield `<spam><bar>key</bar><foo>value</foo></spam>` for each K,V pairs.

Comment: Yes, when inline=false, and when inline=true than they should represent the name of the attribute for the mentioned element. Since only value="value" would used, than it would be just logical to inline only that part, so the key would remain as text. If both value="value" and key="key" would be present, than the result should look like: <entry value="xxx" key="yyy"/>. I think just that would be "simple", as the developers market their framework :).

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work like that. `inline` leaves the value as text. and the attribute only refers to the key, not the value. Try it for yourself. You still get 
    `<foo>
   <property key="key2">value2</property>
   <property key="key">value</property>
   </foo>`

(the above is actual output with `inline=true`)

Comment: Yes, indeed :( . Sorry for that: I would have 100% expected to work like I described above (I've used SimpleXML in a few projects and I also recommended it everywhere, but this behavior here is really counter-intuitive).

Comment: Doesn't matter, in the end I just ripped the key,value pair into a separate class and got it working the way I wanted (actually more flexibly). I never needed the O(1) access by keys.

Comment: Hey, since you're the only person who replied, I'm giving you the answer, even if it doesn't fix.