# Sample XML HashMap for SimpleXML

Tags: java, android

Using the `SimpleXML` lib for Android is it possible to create a HashMap out of these:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>chicken</name>
        <amount>13</amount>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>potatoes</name>
        <amount>3</amount>
    </item>
</items>
```

I want to create a HashMap that would contain the id and the Item, like this:

```
HashMap<Integer, Item>
```

where the ID would be the id of the item (the value itself). Is this possible?

I tried by creating the Item class which holds the id, name and amount:

```
class Item {
@Element(name=id)
public int id;

@Element(name="name")
public String name;

@Element(name="amount")
public int amount;
```

}

And then created wrapper like

```
class Items {

@ElementMap(@field="item", keyType=Integer.class, valueType=Item.class)
private Map<Integer, Item> mItems = new HashMap<Integer, Item>();

// .. getters / setters
```

}

But it fails to find the corresponding fields...

When I use List instead of HashMap - it works as expected. I just need HashMap as addition to the list field in Items wrapper class.

Any help?

Comment: Oh come on, it doesn't even look like you tried..

Comment: added details... now can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Is this maybe something that might help you with that:

[How to serialize a Map<String, String> using Simple XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353500/how-to-serialize-a-mapstring-string-using-simple-xml) 
and
http://old.nabble.com/Serializing-collections-with-both-SimpleXML-annotated-and-not-annotated-types-td19679788.html

It doesn't explicitly point to a integer,String hashmap but it will show the idea.

Comment: Small detail, just blind guess but: @ElementMap(@field="item", keyType=Integer.class, valueType=Item.class)
When you see @field = "item". Shouldn't this correspond with the class (Capital I) ? Further then that, I do not have an idea what would solve it atm.