# Serialize a Treemap<String, String> using Simple XML

Tags: java, simple-framework

I've created a wrapper class like below (is this necessary? I tried serializing the treemap directly without making any wrapper class and it failed) following the answer provided in a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353500/how-to-serialize-a-mapstring-string-using-simple-xml).

```
@Root
public class Example {

   @ElementMap(entry="property", value="value", attribute=true, inline=true)
   private TreeMap<String, String> map;

    public Example()
    {
        map = new TreeMap<String, String>() {
            {
                put("testing1", "a");
                put("testing2", "b");
                put("testing3", "c");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Then I try to serialize it with the code below:

```
Serializer serializer = new Persister();
Example example = new Example();
File result = new File("example.xml");
serializer.write(example, result);
```

The example.xml file is generated, but it is an empty file. Is it because Treemap is not supported by Simple XML? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Which version are you using? I've tried your code and it generated the file successfully.

Comment: Version 2.7.1. Really? that's good to hear! I'm using this code in Android development not sure if that makes a difference.. Let me clean the project and try again.

Comment: Yeah, try for yourself on an stand alone java application to check. Are you sure your Android App have the needed permissions to write in that file?

Comment: I cleaned my project, rebuild everything and it works this time.. I'm not sure why it didn't.. well hopefully someone will find the above example code useful to serialize a treemap because I couldn't find a working example anywhere. Cheers and thanks @EvertonAgner !!

Comment: You're welcome! Anyways, I've responded to your question on some thoughts about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, I've tried your code and it ran with no problems (on a stand-alone java app). So, my thoughts on what was happening would be:

- Any compilation or classpath issue, which would probably be corrected
  on project cleanup
- If you are debugging it on a physical phone, something may have happened on which it didn't let the program write on that file
- Your app may had any problem with permissions on writing that file

Anyways, here's the generated file:

```
<example>
   <property string="testing1" value="a"/>
   <property string="testing2" value="b"/>
   <property string="testing3" value="c"/>
</example>
```

Comment: Yes I was debugging on my phone probably something happened. Cleaning up the project did the trick :)